# Appending Data From One Table To Another Where Criteria Matches - Access

Tags: ms-access, append, ms-access-2003, insert-update

I am running Access 2003 and I have two tables "tblEUPrograms" and "tblEUProgramPayments". Programs has a field with an id and a name, ProgramPayments has a field with an id but no name. I have created a field for the name in ProgramPayments but obviously it is empty for all rows. What I want to do is append all names from from Programs to ProgramPayments where id field is the same for both tables. I'm sure this is simple but for the life of me I just cant figure out how to do this using access append query (I most likely have the syntax wrong). Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It is against normalization rules, you can get the information from a query.

Comment: it's not an append that you need - try an update query.

Comment: Hey Don,

Thanks - I ran an update query instead and it is working.